# Weird Subversion permissions issue

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to set up SVN on a CentOS 5 system so that several people can use a repository.

- I've created the repository at `/var/svnrepository`.
- I added a `subversion` user and group, made that the owner of the repository recursively.
- I set permissions to 775 recursively.
- I ensured that all the system users are in the `subversion` group.

The problem I'm running into is that when I do a commit, SVN apparently creates a file called `db/current` and it has my username and group. So say my username is `jimbo`...

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jimbo      jimbo         11 Dec  2 01:09 current
```

Then after that no one else can check anything out. They get a permission denied error.

There's also a similar issue with a file called `db/format`.

```
Can not open file /var/svnrepository/contactdb/trunk/format: Permission denied
```

Has anyone else seen this? Know of a solution?

All repository access is through ssh.

The weird thing is, I've set up SVN on Linux before and never had this problem. I don't know what I'm doing differently this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, that usually the setGID is set on Subversions repository directory and their child directories:

```
drwxr-sr-x svnowner svnusers 4096 2008-11-01 .
```

by chmod 775 you unset this setGID bit and thats why the problems occurred:

The setGID means: if you create a file, the group will be set to **svnusers**(in my example), not your primary group.

I bet you do no have the SetGID bit set, do you?

However, it is better to change GID of the folders:

```
chmod g+s <REPO>/dir
```

it is best you look into a fresh created repository to match the permissions.

Comment: I bet changing the primary group of the users to svnusers would work, but it seems like a hack to do it.  It would mean that subversion hijacks unix permissions, changing at a basic level how you can secure the system.

Comment: it is a hack. Usually the setGID bit is set on repository directory. If it is set, always the correct group would be set

Comment: This appears to work. I ran `chmod -R g+s`. Now the whole repository is `rwxrws--- subversion subversion`. Users are in `subversion` group. We'll see if that works. If not I'll look into Apache or svnserv but I was hoping to avoid running another daemon.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using svnserve or is everyone going through `file:///` URI's?  Subversion recommends [against the second](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#reposperms). `svnserve -d` should be run as a single user.

Here is some [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html) on trying to make multiple access methods work.

Comment: Every one is accessing it through ssh, like this: `svn co svn+ssh://host.com/var/repository`

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the documentation about creating a wrapper script for svnserve that sets the umask to 002? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s05.html

Comment: It isn't really 100% clear to me, but from what I understand I'm not actually using svnserv. Just accessing the repository through ssh.